# How to check if dropdown is toggle on and add class

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I want to check if the dropdown menu is toggled. If the menu has a class: mega-toggle-on then add a class to id #submenu-new.

Here is my code:

```
  <div id="submenu-new" class="submenu-balk active" style="padding-top: 226px;">

      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
if ( jQuery( "#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_1 ul li" ).is( ".mega-toggle-on" ) ) {

 jQuery("#submenu-new").addClass("active");
alert('ss');

}
</script>
```

[Example where you can find the mega-toggle-on class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T9p3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```js
if ($("#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_1 ul li").hasClass("mega-toggle-on")) {
    $("#submenu-new").addClass("active");
}
```

You can find documentation of `hasClass` of jQuery [here](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasClass` in jQuery

```
if ( jQuery( "#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_1 ul li" ).hasClass( "mega-toggle-on" ) ) {
jQuery("#submenu-new").addClass("active");
} else {
jQuery("#submenu-new").removeClass("active");}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using JQuery, you can use hasClass to check whether given class is exists at the current moment and if exists you can change class to the otherClass.

```
if ( jQuery( "#mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_1 ul li" ).hasClass( "mega-toggle-on" ) ) { // class "mega-toggle-on" exists...
  jQuery("#submenu-new").addClass("active");
} else {  // class "mega-toggle-on" does not exists...
  jQuery("#submenu-new").removeClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you Comment, but it doenst work. The active was not added to the id:submenu-new. do I have to add a $( document ).ready?

Comment: Yes, if it still doesn't solve your problem you can use JQuery $( document ).ready() function.